# ReportServer: no report with an empty table

Tags: reportserver

I use the Report Server from Datewerks.
I have created a report, just as the time-scheduler report.
But how can I set the report so that it sends no report if no data (rows) are available in the table?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently two possibilities how this may be accomplished in [ReportServer](http://reportserver.net). The first is to use conditional scheduling. Here you would need to create a condition that allows to check whether or not your report has any data. Conditions themselves are Dynamic List (variants) and are created via the terminal command *rcondition*. Once a condition is in place it can be selected during the scheduling process (by activating the *advanced* options on the first panel. To get you started, have a look at [the manual](https://reportserver.net/en/guides/admin/chapters/Scheduling-of-Reports/).

The second possibility is to use ReportServer's scripting capabilities and to hook into the scheduler. This works particularly well if you are interested only in Dynamic List reports because here it can easily be determined if the report contains any data or not. (For Jasper or BIRT reports, for example, it is not clear how to determine if the report contains data, since the reporting engine might still generate a PDF/document with several pages.)

The hook you are looking for is the *SchedulerExecutionHook* which is called before any scheduled job is executed and which may veto the execution. Following is a little script that checks whether a) the scheduled job is a report execution job, b) the report is a Dynamic List. If these conditions are met it runs the report and then checks if the result has data or not. If this is not the case it vetoes the execution.

```
import net.datenwerke.scheduler.service.scheduler.hooks.SchedulerExecutionHook
import net.datenwerke.scheduler.service.scheduler.hooks.adapter.SchedulerExecutionHookAdapter
import net.datenwerke.rs.scheduler.service.scheduler.jobs.report.ReportExecuteJob
import net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.reportengines.table.entities.TableReport
import net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.reportengines.table.output.object.CompiledTableReport
import net.datenwerke.scheduler.service.scheduler.helper.SkipJobExecution

def callback = [
  doesVetoExecution : { job, logEntry ->
    if(job instanceof ReportExecuteJob &&
       job.getReport() instanceof TableReport){
       job.doExecute()
       if(job.getExecutedReport() instanceof CompiledTableReport &&
          ! job.getExecutedReport().hasData()){
          return new SkipJobExecution("No data")
       }
    }
  }
  ] as SchedulerExecutionHookAdapter

def HOOK_NAME = "SkipEmptyListSchedulerHook";
GLOBALS.services.callbackRegistry.attachHook(HOOK_NAME, SchedulerExecutionHook.class, callback)
```

To register the hook, place it in the fileserver's bin/onstartup.d folder in which case the hook is registered whenever the server starts up. In order not to restart the server but register it directly open the Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and execute the script by hand (exec command). For an introduction to scripting see the [Scripting Guide](https://reportserver.net/en/guides/script/main/) (in particular [Chapter 7](https://reportserver.net/en/guides/script/chapters/Tapping-into-ReportServer/)).

I should add, that this is not really an optimal implementation. What happens here is that in order to decide whether or not the email should be sent the report is executed. If it is not vetoed the report will be executed again as part of the actual process. As far as I know, there is, however, not much that can currently be done about this. A possible optimization would be to not simply run the report but adapt it with a *LIMIT 1*.